# Curl JSON POST request to Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, curl

I am newbie in Rails and I am trying to create an engine in rails. The point is to send JSON data to app in this format `{city: "Berlin", country: "Germany"}` and receive back same JSON, but with reversed values like `{city: "nilreB"}` and so on. 
My route is:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  post "collect/data" => 'data#create'
end
```

My controller is:

```
class DataController < ApplicationController
  def create
    render text: "#{request.body}"
  end
end
```

I know that controller is not finished at all, but I am wondering why I am getting HTTP error when I am making POST request like:

```
curl -v -d '{"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2"}' http://0.0.0.0:3000/collect/data --header "Accept: application/json" --header "Content-Type: application/json"
```

> HTTP/1.1 204 No Content

I have read that is fine when you use Rails 5, I am using it. So my question is am I missing something in controller or somewhere else? I would be much appreciated for any help.

These are logs:

```
INFO -- : [df2105a8-e2c5-4e27-a9c7-ffc91c8b92e8] Started POST "/collect/data" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-02-09 20:26:49 +0000
INFO -- : [df2105a8-e2c5-4e27-a9c7-ffc91c8b92e8] Processing by DataController#create as JSON
INFO -- : [df2105a8-e2c5-4e27-a9c7-ffc91c8b92e8] Parameters: {"key1"=>"value1", "key2"=>"value2", "datum"=>{"key1"=>"value1", "key2"=>"value2"}}
INFO -- : [df2105a8-e2c5-4e27-a9c7-ffc91c8b92e8] No template found for DataController#create, rendering head :no_content
INFO -- : [df2105a8-e2c5-4e27-a9c7-ffc91c8b92e8] Completed 204 No Content in 1ms
```

Comment: Can you show all of your data controller?

Comment: From what you've shown here, everything should be working just fine. I didn't trust my intuition so I double-checked it with both Rails 5.0 and 5.1. Another hint: you don't even need to manually read the body. The data will be available in `params[:datum]` (singular of *data*, via inflection).

Comment: @LioraHaydont I have added full DataController

Comment: @ma_il thanks for the hint! It is responding with 200 code if I use `params[:datum]` in my action. So all that I need to do is reverse values. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @ma_il said my parameters are available in DataController as `params[:datum]`, I have searched a bit more about params in Rails 5.1 which I am using and discovered that my full amswer is:

```
def create
  my_hash = params[:datum].permit!
  render json: my_hash.to_h.collect { |keys, values| "#{keys}{values.reverse}" }
end
```